# Problema de enrutamiento en produccion con react y express

Tags: reactjs, express, react-router-dom

estoy terminando un sistema de gestion para una empresa que tiene que tener una integración con su viejo sistema ya que hay reportes y herramientas que aún no desarrollé. El proyecto esta hecho con React, vite, material ui y React router dom en su version 6.12.1 y hago el enrutamiento como si fuera un objeto.

Por el lado del servidor, es un servidor en express y ambos proyectos estan desplegados en producción.

El problema que estoy experimentando es precisamente que como tengo que hacer las integraciones entre el sistema nuevo y el viejo, a la hora de colocar la url de un informe del sistema nuevo, me da un 404 not found. Por ejemplo https://sistemaNuevo.com/app/reports/sales y me lanza un 404 pero si me logueo e ingreso desde la navegacion del sistema puedo acceder bien y sin problemas, siendo que es la misma url.

No entiendo bien si el problema es del lado del servidor o es un problema como configure el enrutamiento.

Pero si entiendo viendo la consola en network que intenta acceder al recurso como si fuera un archivo y obviamente no lo encuentra.

Dejo el codigo del archivo router:

```
    export const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element:<Login/>
  },
  {
    path: "/app",
    element: <Layout />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "home",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "reports",
        element: <ReportLayout/>,
        children:[
          {
            path:'dailySales',
            element: <Sales />,
          },
          {
            path:'dailySalesFranchise',
            element: <SalesFranchise />,
          },
          {
            path: "cmv",
            element: <CMV />,
          },
          {
            path: "sectorizedSales",
            element: <Sector />,
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "tools",
        element: <ToolLayout/>,
        children:[
          {
            path:'addSales',
            element: <AddSales />,
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "dev",
        element:<DevLayout/>,
        children:[
          {
            path:'connection',
            element: <ConnectionPage />,
          },
         
        ]
      },
      
    ],
  }
]);
```

Algo importante, es que yo en Layout ya hago una verificación si el usuario esta logueado o no, si no lo esta, lo redirigo al login, pero nisiquiera me lleva a la pagina de error que establecí.

El codigo del index del back es este:

```
    const corsOptions = {
    origin: backURL.ApiUrl, 
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true, 
};
  
  // Aplicar el middleware de CORS

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(express.json());




const httpServer = app.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT} `);
});

app.use('/', express.static('dist'))
app.use('/api/user',userRouter)
app.use('/api/sales',salesRouter)
app.use('/api/franchise',franchiseRouter)
app.use('/api/projections',projectionsRouter)
app.use('/api/expenses',expensesRouter)
app.use('/api/operativeCost',operativeCostRouter)
app.use('/api/connectionBranch',connectionBranch)
app.use('/api/sector',sectorRouter)

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).redirect('https://sistemaNuevo.com/'); //Accede directamente al login
});
```

La ultima linea fue para evitar una pagina de 404. Me gustaria saber por donde puede estar el problema y cual puede ser una solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un problema que pasa al crear SPA usando express.js, para eso hay una libreria. [connect-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback)

```
var history = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
app.use(history());
```

Answer (score -1):

Muy buen recurso el connect-history-api-fallback. Pude solucionar el problema, dejo el codigo de como lo implemente por que el orden influye:

```
app.use('/api/user',userRouter)
app.use('/api/sales',salesRouter)
app.use('/api/franchise',franchiseRouter)
app.use('/api/projections',projectionsRouter)
app.use('/api/expenses',expensesRouter)
app.use('/api/operativeCost',operativeCostRouter)
app.use('/api/connectionBranch',connectionBranch)
app.use('/api/sector',sectorRouter)
app.use(history());
app.use('/', express.static('dist'))
```

Comment: Me alegro de que mi solución te funcionara, agradecería que marques que te resolvió el problema :)